# Need to stop the automatic start of login manager (Antergos, GNOME)

Tags: gnome, nvidia, lightdm, antergos

I'm trying to install an NVIDIA Driver, but I must turn off the Xserver first. I've tried a lot of methods I found online, but none seem to work.

I'm using Antergos with GNOME.

- **Ctrl + Alt + Backspace** kills the server, but then the graphical login screen starts again.
- `sudo service stop lightdm` says there isn't a command *service*
- Tried switching with **Ctrl + Alt + f1** and then killing the server (with `kill` or `pkill`), but that had two outcomes: It did nothing or I got a blackscreen
- `systemd <\something>` also says there's no such command (*systemd*)
- Installing the drivers with pacman crashes my Antergos install and I must do a new install

**EDIT**: Turned out that my Graphics Card supports optimus and I managed to install the drivers following this wiki post: [Bumblebee for NVIDIA](https://antergos.com/wiki/hardware/graphics/bumblebee-for-nvidia-optimus/)

Answer (score 2):

From the commands you are using, I take it that you use Systemd and LightDM.

The correct command to stop the display server is

```
sudo systemctl stop lightdm
```

I think it's safe to run from a graphical terminal, not only from TTY. If you want to disable auto starting of LightDM altogether, replace `stop` with `disable`.

Note that stopping the X server, even from a TTY may switch back to the TTY the X server ran in, so if you get a blackscreen, switch to another TTY.

If you want to restart LightDM, use

```
sudo systemctl start lightdm
```